# Solspace Supersearch - Searching entries based on a checkbox field

Tags: solspace, supersearch

I'm using the Solspace Supersearch add-on and am trying to search entries based on a checkbox field. Currently I'm getting all entries within the results. I've tried using name="users-exact" and this doesn't help to filter the returned data either.
Suggestions appreciated,
Thanks!

```
<form method="post" action="{path='search/results'}/">
    {exp:super_search:search}
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{csrf_token}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="inclusive_keywords" value="no" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_post" value="no" /> 
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Under 16" name="users[]"/> Under 16</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="16-18" name="users[]"/> 16 - 18</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="18 and over" name="users[]"/> 18 and over</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Women" name="users[]"/> Women</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Men" name="users[]"/> Men</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
    {/exp:super_search:search}
    </form>

{exp:super_search:results channel="zoo_visitor" inclusive_keywords="no" status="Services-id5"}
    <a href="{site_url}directory/view/{if visitor:member_id}{visitor:member_id}{if:else}{entry_id}{/if}">{firstname}</a>
    <p>{building}, {street}, {town}, {county}</p>
    {/exp:super_search:results}
```

Comment: That's only 1 half of the equation. What's the code for your results page?

Comment: ...and what version of EE and Super Search are you using? Also, what's the fieldtype of your `{users}` custom field? Is it set as searchable? Have you tried sending a _string_ of data instead of an _array_ (using `name="users"` instead of `name="users[]"`)?

Comment: See updated code for results page.The fieldtype is checkboxes and are set to searchable, setting name="users" also doesn't work, I've only got it to work using value="users-empty", however, this is not the output I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by allowing the use of keywords and using javascript to enter the checkbox values into a hidden supersearch "keywords" input. While I still don't know why the checkbox inputs are not filtering the results, this approach is giving me the correct output.
Thanks!